# Cannot save a url as a value in a PropertiesConfiguration object

Tags: java

This one has me stumped.

I have something like:

```
PropertiesConfiguration pc = new PropertiesConfiguration();
pc.setProperty("url", "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/somedb");
pc.setBasePath(".");
pc.setFileName("my.properties");
```

I have this code in a jar that was built on Linux.  When it gets run on a Windows box, then the file that gets saved comes out like:

```
url = jdbc:postgres:\/\/localhost:5432/somedb.
```

This file is going to get consumed by some python code, and it's not at all happy with that URL.

I've searched and searched, but for the life of me, I don't understand why PC would be escaping a forward slash.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue i was able to resolve it by using backward slash. Try to use '\' instead of '/' for windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not the colons rather than the forward slashes which get escaped?

I tried this with java.util.Properties:

```
public class PropertiesTest {  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("url", "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/somedb");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("my.properties");
    props.store(out, null);
  }
}
```

The output to file is:

```
url=jdbc\:postgres\://localhost\:5432/somedb
```

This is as documented in [Properties.store](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), which says

> The key and element characters #, !,
>   =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are
>   properly loaded.

I suspect your solution will be to use straight write to file, rather than going through Properties, e.g.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File props = new File("my_raw.properties");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(props));
    writer.write("url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/somedb");
    writer.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in version 2.0, which is undergoing development now.  Having updated my dependency to commons-configuration-2.0-SNAPSHOT, I no longer get slash characters escaped (when used in a value).